# Обтекание текста вокруг View элемента в ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, textview

Есть ли реализация обтекания текста в разметке `xml` в контейнере `Constraint`, без программной реализации, если только программное, не подскажите как осуществить это. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]